# simple but useful powershell script not working

Tags: windows, powershell, debugging, scripting

this script prompts to .txt all dll used by an exe to all exe running

```
Get-Process |
    ForEach-Object {
        $procName = $_.Name
        tasklist /m /fi "imagename eq $procName.exe" > $procName.txt
    }
```

I run it in powershell but its "loading" and not giving me the output, but I cant find the problem.

Comment: What is `"loading"`?

Comment: question was clear to me, and I provided the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below (note that I used an already created c:\tests folder):

```
Get-Process |
    ForEach-Object {
        $procName = $_.Name
        tasklist /m /fi "imagename eq $procName.exe" > "c:\tests\$($procName).txt"
    }
```

Comment: As a bit of a nit-pick, but `$procName` isn't needed:  `tasklist /m /fi "imagename eq $($_.Name).exe" > "$($_.Name).txt"`.  Also, I'd recommend not calling external programs unless it is absolutely necessary.